# How to stop flexbox from wrapping words and creating equal width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a panel that looks something like this:

```
-------------------------------------------
|                              |          |
|       Ready   3  Not Ready 2 |   Total  |
|   A                          |    16    |
|       Talking 4  Outbound 3  |          |
-------------------------------------------
```

My first thought was to do this with CSS `flexbox` and I was able to get very close. The issue I am running into is the middle section of the panel that shows `Ready, Not Ready, Talking, and Outbound`. I would like each item to be equal width and have no word wrap.

I was able to get them equal width. However, I cant stop the items from word wrapping. Does anyone know what I am missing?

```css
.panel {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.panel>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.panel-row {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.panel-stats {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.panel-grid-row {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.panel-grid-item {
  background: tomato;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-container">
    <div class="panel-icon">A</div>
    <div class="panel-stats">
      <div class="panel-grid-row">
        <div class="panel-grid-item">Ready 7</div>
        <div class="panel-grid-item">Not Ready 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-grid-row">
        <div class="panel-grid-item">Talking 4</div>
        <div class="panel-grid-item">Outbound 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-total panel-row">
      <div class="total-label">Total</div>
      <div class="total-num">16</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Michael_B - Thanks for the reply, but `white-space:nowrap` takes away the equal widths.

Comment: @Michael_B - that makes sense. I was hoping I wouldn't have to explicitly specify the width either, but it does solve my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `nowrap` is computed *after* the width of the container is established.

Since the container's width is set to the default `auto`, this length is computed first based on the length of the wrapping text.

Then `nowrap` is applied, which obviously lengthens the text, which overflows the previously established container width.

```css
.panel {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.panel>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.panel-row {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.panel-stats {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.panel-grid-row {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.panel-grid-item {
  background: tomato;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  white-space: nowrap; /* equal width works if you remove nowrap */
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-container">
    <div class="panel-icon">A</div>
    <div class="panel-stats">
      <div class="panel-grid-row">
        <div class="panel-grid-item" style="background-color: yellow">Ready 7</div>
        <div class="panel-grid-item" style="background-color: lightgreen">Not Ready 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-grid-row">
        <div class="panel-grid-item" style="background-color: yellow">Talking 4</div>
        <div class="panel-grid-item" style="background-color: lightgreen">Outbound 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-total panel-row">
      <div class="total-label">Total</div>
      <div class="total-num">16</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The simplest solution (if it's an option) would be to define the width of the container.

```css
.panel {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.panel>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.panel-row {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.panel-stats {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.panel-grid-row {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 200px;  /* NEW */
}

.panel-grid-item {
  background: tomato;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;  /* NEW */
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="panel-container">
    <div class="panel-icon">A</div>
    <div class="panel-stats">
      <div class="panel-grid-row">
        <div class="panel-grid-item" style="background-color: yellow">Ready 7</div>
        <div class="panel-grid-item" style="background-color: lightgreen">Not Ready 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-grid-row">
        <div class="panel-grid-item" style="background-color: yellow">Talking 4</div>
        <div class="panel-grid-item" style="background-color: lightgreen">Outbound 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-total panel-row">
      <div class="total-label">Total</div>
      <div class="total-num">16</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```